# GLASSFISH CONNECTION TO DATABASE

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

[Picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1PEq.png)I get the following error when I try to create a connection pool with glassfish server. Im using netbeans and derby as my IDE and Database respectively.

```
Caused by: ERROR 08004: Connection authentication failure occurred.  Reason: Userid or password invalid.
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.mapSecchkcd(NetConnection.java:1158)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.securityCheckComplete(NetConnection.java:947)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseSECCHKRM(NetConnectionReply.java:582)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.parseSECCHKreply(NetConnectionReply.java:235)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnectionReply.readSecurityCheck(NetConnectionReply.java:74)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.readSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(NetConnection.java:787)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowSecurityCheckAndAccessRdb(NetConnection.java:724)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowUSRIDONLconnect(NetConnection.java:565)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.flowConnect(NetConnection.java:359)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.initialize(NetConnection.java:274)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetConnection.<init>(NetConnection.java:228)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl.newNetConnection(ClientJDBCObjectFactoryImpl.java:295)
    at org.apache.derby.client.BasicClientDataSource.getConnectionX(BasicClientDataSource.java:1495)
    at org.apache.derby.client.BasicClientDataSource.getConnection(BasicClientDataSource.java:1446)
    ... 63 more
|#]
```

I expect it to ping without errors.